# Applying a 'Yes' flag to all first instances of date for each type of account

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to evaluate the first instance of dates for each account. For example, I'd like to create a new column that indicates "Yes" for the earliest date (even if that same date repeats) and "No" for any later dates on the same account.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2018-08-01','2018-08-01','2018-08-02','2018-08-03','2019-09-01','2019-09-02','2019-09-03','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-10-04','2020-10-05'],
                     'account':['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','d','e']})
test
```

[image]

The output should appear like:

[image]

I'm seeing that these steps I am taking won't work because the first row index should be "Yes" when it is returning a "No".

```
new_test = test.merge(pd.DataFrame(test.groupby('account')['date'].min().reset_index()),left_on='account',right_on='account')
new_test

first_har = []
for item in new_test['date_y'].duplicated():
    if item == False:
        first_har.append('Yes')
    else:
        first_har.append('No')
print(first_har)

pd.concat([new_test,pd.DataFrame(first_har)],axis=1)
```

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this with a `merge` (which could have better performance than iterating through the rows of the first dates).

Start with the same df of first dates that you generated, with a `first_date` column appended:

```
>>> first_dates = test.groupby('account')['date'].min().reset_index().assign(first_date='Yes')
>>> first_dates

  account        date first_date
0       a  2018-08-01        Yes
1       b  2019-09-01        Yes
2       c  2020-01-02        Yes
3       d  2020-10-04        Yes
4       e  2020-10-05        Yes
```

Merge with the original:

```
>>> test.merge(first_dates, how='left')

          date account first_date
0   2018-08-01       a        Yes
1   2018-08-01       a        Yes
2   2018-08-02       a        NaN
3   2018-08-03       a        NaN
4   2019-09-01       b        Yes
5   2019-09-02       b        NaN
6   2019-09-03       b        NaN
7   2020-01-02       c        Yes
8   2020-01-03       c        NaN
9   2020-01-04       c        NaN
10  2020-10-04       d        Yes
11  2020-10-05       e        Yes
```

Note that by default the merge is done on all matched columns, and the `how='left'` ensures that the result gives you a row for each row in `test`.  To get your desired output with Yes/No, just add a missing-values fill:

```
>>> test.merge(first_dates, how='left').fillna({'first_date': 'No'})

          date account first_date
0   2018-08-01       a        Yes
1   2018-08-01       a        Yes
2   2018-08-02       a         No
3   2018-08-03       a         No
4   2019-09-01       b        Yes
5   2019-09-02       b         No
6   2019-09-03       b         No
7   2020-01-02       c        Yes
8   2020-01-03       c         No
9   2020-01-04       c         No
10  2020-10-04       d        Yes
11  2020-10-05       e        Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two steps. First, get minimum date per account. Second, set all values to true where the accounts minimum date matches the date of the row.

```py
# First: get minimum dates per account
gb_first_date = test.groupby(['account']).agg({'date' : np.min})

# Second: set all values to 'Yes' where entry matches first date
test['first_date'] = "No"
for row in gb_first_date.iterrows():
    account = row[0]
    date = row[1].date
    mask = (test.account == account) & (test.date == date)
    test.loc[mask, 'first_date'] = 'Yes'
```

Comment: Thanks much, I like your use of iterrows(). That will help on larger dataset as this was only a portion. Can you provide a bit more detail about what the account = row[0] and date = row[1].date is doing?

Comment: `iterrows` returns a tuple of index and row values. Due to the group by account the index becomes the account values. Therefore `row[0]` is the index and `row[1]` contains all values in that row. To get the value of the date you will need to access the column called `date`.